# Returning data back to 1st Activity when setResult is called from 3rd Activity

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have 3 Activities. When in the 1st Activity, the onClick method is called with startActivityForResult inside it that takes you to Activity 2. Then from Activity 2, you can click another button that takes you to Activity 3.

In Activity 3, I would like to call the setResult method, and after that, it will finish the Activity and take you back to Activity one with the data from Activity 3.

But, for some reason, the data is null and Activity.RESULT_OK is never called.

How can I handle this? thanks.

In Activity one:

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    IVID = view.getId();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, PhotoSelectActivityMultiple.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);


}
```

In Activity 2:

```
     Intent returnIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CollageGrid.class);
                returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("imageurls", mDownloadURL);
                startActivity(returnIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

In Activity 3:

```
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("part",byteArray);
            setResult(1, intent);
            finish();
```

In onActivity

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            updateThis = (ImageView) findViewById(IVID);

            byte[] byteArray = data.getByteArrayExtra("part");
            Bitmap current_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            updateThis.setImageBitmap(current_bmp);
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you call activities in this order `activity1->activity2->activity3` then you do `setResult()` in `activity3` and expect `activity1` to get the result in `onActivityResult` ? is that right?

Comment: @Bhargav Yes, that is what I would like to achieve.

Comment: Do you understand how `setResult` works? when you call activities in certain order, `setResult` travels back in the reverse order activites are launched, so what you need to do is make `onActivityResult()` in `activity2` and pass along the result your recieved (data) in the `setResult()`

Comment: I was just about to suggest that, but, I was thinking it would be a bad idea because I am passing down relatively big byte arrays and maybe that would slow down my application by a lot.

Comment: well I cant think of any other way, except you break the activity2 and 3 into fragments and attach it to activity1

Comment: hmm, yes. That could also be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting Activity 3 by simply calling StartActivity we need to call activity 3 also by StartActivityForResult. So, Activity3 will return the value to Activity2 OnActivityResult, from where you can pass the value to Activity1.